# Can I make Install-SPSolution verbose?

Tags: sharepoint-server, deployment, solution

I'm trying to deploy a farm solution using:

`Install-SPSolution -Identity [bla bla bla] -GACDeployment`

However, the job never seems to finish and doing `Get-SPSolution` shows "False" for the solution "Deployed" column. I've no idea why is not being able to deploy and would like to get a verbose log from Install-SPSolution. Is this possible? I already searched but couldn't find anything. If this is not possible what are the steps I should take to investigate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, there is no option to get verbose. I would say the only way to do that is to do it manually --> meaning you log each step to a text file from start to finish and this will get you a little bit of information on where it stopped (maybe try that on a DEV environment and once you figure the issue and fix it, trim the logging part and deploy to PROD)

Comment: What are the steps to deploy the solution manually?

Comment: sorry I meant in your code. (for example, if the solution has C# code, inside each function you or the developer add a line to logger ==> i.e. Deploying feature ABC, updating master page, and also add in the try catch blocks) [I know it is not the most elegant workaround, but sometimes, it is the only way]

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can do.

1. Enable the Verbose logging for the farm and then deploy the solutions and check the ULS logs.
2. Or use the -Verbose parameter in your  command, which will list all steps in it. like this

   Install-SPSolution -Identity [bla bla bla] -GACDeployment -Verbose
   It will show output like this

   VERBOSE: Leaving BeginProcessing Method of Install-SPSolution.

   VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Install-SPSolution" on target
   "blah blah .wsp".

   VERBOSE: Leaving ProcessRecord Method of Install-SPSolution.

   VERBOSE: Leaving EndProcessing Method of Install-SPSolution.

Or in case of error:

> VERBOSE: Leaving BeginProcessing Method of Install-SPSolution.
>
> VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Install-SPSolution" on target
>   "blahblah.wsp".
>
> Install-SPSolution : A deployment or retraction is
>   already under way for the solution "blahblah.wsp", and only one
>   deployment or retraction at a time is supported. At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-SPSolution -Identity blab lah
>   -GACDeployment ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...InstallSolution:    SPCmdletInstallSolution)
>   [Install-SPSolution], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletInstallS    olution
>
> VERBOSE: Leaving ProcessRecord Method of Install-SPSolution. VERBOSE:
>   Leaving EndProcessing Method of Install-SPSolution.